# Node JS Set Up in Visual Studio Team Services (was VS Online)

Tags: node.js, tfs, tdd, azure-devops

I have we app in VS (Pure HTML). 
In Pre-Build Script,

```
cd $(ProjectDir)
@powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted; 
@powershell  iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
@powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted;
@powershell  choco install nodejs
call npm install
call grunt TaskScripts
```

Its fail, while execute node install.

Help me to resolve this.

**Thanks.**

Comment: How does it fail? No one can help you diagnose an issue without an error message. Think of how you'd react if a user came to you and said "The program doesn't work right." without additional details.

Comment: Do you mean you are using VSTS for your build? Are you using XAML build or vNext build? How does your build definition look like? What do you want to achieve? What's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vNext build, you can add a NPM task in your build definition to install node:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/steps/package/npm-install